# Travelling from Khon Kaen to Lom Sak, is it better to go from bus terminal 1 or bus terminal 3?

Tags: buses, thailand, bangkok

I want to travel from Khon Kaen to Lom Sak.

Is there a bus both from terminal 1 (I mean the old non-air conditioned bus station) and terminal 3 (I mean the new air-conditioned bus station)?

Answer (score 2):

The bus you want is the 874 bus route which is operated by [this company](http://www.phetprasert.com/index2.php?name=timetable&file=r874). The bus takes around 3 hours and 30 minutes.

If you go to [this page](http://www.phetprasert.com/index2.php?name=ticket) and look for Khon Kaen (ขอนแก่น) and look at the stops/ticket offices column (จุดจอด/จุดจำหน่ายตั๋ว) we find this address:

> สถานีขนส่งผู้โดยสารจังหวัดขอนแก่น แห่งที่ 3 (จุดขึ้นรถ และจำหน่ายตั๋ว)

Which when translated means:

> **Khon Kaen Bus Terminal 3 (Bus pick up and ticketing point)**

Therefore, you want terminal 3